# Wordpress. Вывод товаров WP_Query

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wp-query

Товары выводятся. Но проблема в том, что запрос берет 16 товаров, выкидывает 3, которых нет в наличии и выводит на страницу только 13. Как можно сделать, чтобы заброс брал 16 товаров, подходящие по условиям? Товаров больше 100. И на каждой странице пагинации может быть товаров меньше 16

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 16,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'key' => '_stock_status',
        'value' => 'instock'
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Посмотрите на `'meta_query'`, у Вас там указано `'value' => 'instock'`, что в свою очередь значит, выводить только те товары, которые есть в наличии.

Comment: @Simon, мне нужно выводить товары только в наличии. WP_Query не умеет брать нужное количество товаров в зависимости от условий? Тогда какой смысл в posts_per_page?

Comment: Эмм, ну то есть Вы хотите сказать что на 1-й странице выводит например 13 товаров, потому что 3 из них не в наличии, а например на следующей 16-ть?

Comment: И у Вас `meta_query` не верно составлен. Должно быть `'meta_query' => array(array('key' => '_stock_status', value' => 'instock'));`. Ну и есть еще [wc_get_products and WC_Product_Query](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query) которые рекомендуется использовать.

Comment: @Simon, спасибо! meta_query поправил и заработало правильно.